# Method or Data Member not Found Error?

Tags: vb6

Using VB 6 and Crystal Report 9

I want to display an output in the crystal report.  Last week I used VB 6 and Crystal Report 8.5, it was worked fine, but last day I reinstall my Windows XP, VB 6 and crystal report 9.  After that While executing the code it showing “Method or Data Member not Found Error”. I checked the Component and References. It is also same before I used.

Code.

```
CR.ParameterFields(1)
…….
```

CR – Picture Box

Not accepting this lines,

```
CR.ParameterFields
CR.DataFiles
CR.ReportFileName
CR.Action
```

System File was changed or …? What wrong it is?

How to solve this problem? Can any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem a class/method has changed between the two versions of Crystal Reports. Suggest you check the documentation for the specifics.