# Error - Method or data member not found

Tags: vb6, serial-port

I call this method from `Form_Load`, and The error happens in the first line of the code `Private Sub...`. I added the component from toolbox `MSCOMM`

```
 Private Sub OpenPort()
   MSComm1.Settings = "19200,8,N,1"
   MSComm1.CommPort = 4   
   MSComm1.PortOpen = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method or Data Member not Found Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250669/method-or-data-member-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

The error means `MSComm1` does not have a `Settings` property.

What type is `MSComm1`? Is it a control? Try viewing `MSComm1` in the watch window after the error happens. Does it have a `Settings`?

Comment: When I type `MSComm1.` it shows me the suggestions of code, right ? So the `Settings` appears avaliable... X.x

Comment: Method or Data Member not found does indeed mean that you are calling either a method that isn't in the interface, or passing arguments to the method that aren't in its definition.

Answer (score 0):

The error was:

I Forgot to use `Exit Sub` after the lat line of code, and before the `End Sub`

Comment: that's a weird "fix" to an error, you don't really need Exit Sub, it doesn't cause errors if you don't have it in your sub.

Comment: I didn't get it too >.> but when I write this, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You have write

```
 MSComm1.Settings = "19200,8,N,1"

***write this***

 MSComm1.Settings = "19200,N,8,1"
```

Misplacing of N and 8.