# compile error: method or data member not found in vb6

Tags: vb6

Hi all I am a php developer but since working in an organisation I got a work on a vb6 project.

The software is quite old let say atleast 10 year and I don't know vb6 at all. But still I manage to solve some errors but now I stuck on and I didn't get any solution. I have got this error when compiling the project, highlighting this code.

with `.Panels(6) =` selected.

```
Public Sub StatusBarDateTime()
''    FrmMain.Stb1.Panels(5) = Time
    FrmMain.Stb1.Panels(6) = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
End Sub
```

and when I delete this line on code it show another error that

```
Compile error:
Sub or Function not defined
```

highlighting this line of codes

```
Private Sub MDIForm_Load()
StatusBarDateTime
End Sub
```

I assumed that it is declaring the function. so I delete this function also.

Now after deleting this when I compiled againg I got this error saying that

```
Run time error'481'
Invalid picture
```

and when I click on debug it shows this line of code

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
FrmMain.Show
Dim strUser As String
Call Center_Align(FrmLogin)
OpenConnection
strUser = "select * from TMUser order by login_name"
rsUser.Open strUser, conpgdhm, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Set CmbUserID = rsUser
CmbUserID = "login_name"
CmbUserID = "login_id"
End Sub
```

highlihting `Set CmbUserID = rsUser` line. and now I got nothing.

I don't know how many error may I get after resolving this but that is the next part.
First I have to solve this. I have no idea how to resolve this.

I am banging my head around for two days now, If someone can help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your post is confusing. What is the code causing the error?

Comment: when I compile the project the code where i got problem is on this function `Public Sub StatusBarDateTime()`

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't just go deleting lines of code and functions willy nilly... Restore the project from SourceSafe or your backups and start again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method or Data Member not Found Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250669/method-or-data-member-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

Those were helpful....
The reason it's stopping there is because you are attempting to assign a datareader (or whatever object type rsUser is) as the value to a string or int type (CmbUserID)
You are trying to fit a whole bag of rectangles into a round whole. This is in reference to your latest error only. Based on what I see here, you lack the experience in VB6 to continue without some assistance. I suggest a consultant.
Hope this helps.